# MonoDevelop Designer GTK# Get Button to show Stock Icon

Tags: gtk, monodevelop, gtk#

I am having some issues getting my button in the designer GUI to show the stock icons. I have the button set to "text and icon" with an icon selected however the text is only showing... No icon. Some of the stuff I have read talk about solutions for when you are creating a button from code. However I am creating the button in the designer. It would be pretty annoying if I have to address each button in code to change it to show the stock image.

Comment: The code sample you saw was taking the GtkImage that's inside the GtkButton and manually showing it. You should be able to do this with the GUI editor. Does MonoDevelop not expose access to the GtkButton's child? A GtkButton is a GtkBin, so it has 1 child (and for a GtkButton with text/image it would be a GtkBox).

Comment: @andlabs I don't see anything in the GUI editor got GtkButton child

Comment: Is this GTK# 2 or GTK# 3? And how do I create a new GUI file in MonoDevelop? I personally don't use it but installed it (and GTK# 3) now and don't see an option to create a GUI file in File > New > File...

Answer (score 0):

If it still helps you: when you use the designer, select your button and go into the properties tab. There you can change the button properties from "Text Only" to "Stock button" or "Text & Icon". Using "Stock Button" gives you a selection of stock icons you can choose feom. Using "Text & Icon" lets you set a custom label and lets you load custom made icons (and also stock icons) into a Pixbuf.